# Timeout error with any post script when idle too long

Tags: mysql, timeout, php

I'm using cookies for the user; no session data.  On ANY form where you post data there is a timeout error when you're idle for 2 - 3 min.

This is what happens when you login.

```
$_COOKIE['user_id'] = 1;
$expire = time() + 60 * 60 * 24 * 365;
setcookie('user_login', $_COOKIE['user_id'], $expire);
```

This is the php.ini; things that are applicable to the problem...

```
max_input_time = 10080
max_execution_time = 10080
session.gc_maxlifetime = 10080
memory_limit = 100M
```

I'm using shared GoDaddy shared hosting and supposedly they've troubleshooted everything.  However, I've tried EVERYTHING to fix this with no resolution.  Here'a screenshot of the error...

[image]

I'm about to go crazy.  I have 20 writers and when this sporadically happens it's horrible.  Any idea at all on what might be causing this?  Thank you.

Comment: I just went on uplup.com and it took like 30 secs to load from a blank page before I saw anything, what kind of plan you on as I saw that all thumb images are full size (640×431) and not cached into the browser this will involve quite abit of band width wastage.

Comment: Totally, I have to do something about the thumbs.  Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 0):

try and set your cookie expiration to 1 hour and see if that helps:

```
$expire = time()+3600;  /* expire in 1 hour */
```

Comment: Nope, same exact error.  I tested it maybe 20 - 25 times and concluded it's at exactly 90 seconds of inactivity.  Would that give you any indication of what it might be?

Comment: Are you using some type of CMS or login script?

Comment: Custom login script, it's pretty simple though.  No session data at all.  I re-wrote the whole user system in cookies today to try and resolve this problem.  Same result though...